# Invalid Schema error in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a web page. This is the code:

```
    ## getting links from a web page in a form of list
    def get_list(url) :
        for i in range(262) :
            url = "http://pann.nate.com/search/talk? 
       searchType=A&q=%EB%AF%B8%EC%84%B8%EB%A8%BC%EC%A7%80&page=1".format(i)
            response = requests.get(url)
            my_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
         return my_soup.body.select("a")
    list = get_list(url)

   ## getting the links and make as a list
    def get_link(list) :
        ls = []
        for i in range(0, len(list)) :
            link = list[i].get('href')
            ls.append(link)
        return ls

    ls = get_link(list)

    ## scraping the content from each link  
    def get_text(link) :
        response = requests.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
        text = soup.select_one("#contentArea").text
        return text

    text = get_text(ls)
```

However, I get this error message after I run "text":

```
In[30]: text = get_text(ls)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-30-a4e9a7e8cd0f>", line 1, in <module>
  text = get_text(ls)

  File "<ipython-input-29-1d89fe03762f>", line 2, in get_text
  response = requests.get(link)

   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 508, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 612, in send
adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)

    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in get_adapter
raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)

 InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 
 '['http://www.nate.com/?f=pann', 'http://pann.nate.com/', 
 'http://news.nate.com/', 'http://sports.news.nate.com/index', 
 'http://news.nate.com/ent/index', 'http://www.nate.com/', 
 'http://www.nate.com/sitemap/', '#', '#', '#', 'http://pann.nate.com/', 
 'http://pann.nate.com/talk', 'http://pann.nate.com/talk/imageTheme/index', 
 'http://pann.nate.com/fantalk', 'http://pann.nate.com/video', '#', 
 'http://pann.nate.com/search?q=%EB%AF%B8%EC%84%B8%EB%A8%BC%EC%A7%80', 
 'http://pann.nate.com/search/talk?q=%EB%AF%B8%EC%84%B8%EB%A8%BC%EC%A7%80', 
 'http://pann.nate.com/search/fantalk?q=%EB%AF%B8%EC%84%B8%EB%A8%BC%EC%A7%80', 'http://pann.nate.com/search/video?q=%EB%AF%B8%EC%84%B8%EB%A8%BC%EC%A7%80', 'http://pann.nate.com/talk/342035421', 
'http://pann.nate.com/talk/342035421', 'http://pann.nate.com/talk/c20025', 
'http://pann.nate.com/search/talk?q=%E3%85%87%E3%85%87&searchType=N', 
'http://pann.nate.com/talk/342038400', 
'http://pann.nate.com/talk/342038400', 'http://pann.nate.com/talk/c20038', 
'http://pann.nate.com/search/talk?q=%E3%85%87%E3%85%87&searchType=N', 
'http://pann.nate.com/talk/341991386',
```

The message goes on and on... What seems to be the problem? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Can you post the full code?  `url` is not defined here.

Comment: it's "http://pann.nate.com/search/talk?%20searchType=A&q=%EB%AF%B8%EC%84%B8%EB%A8%BC%EC%A7%80&page=1"

Answer (score 0):

In python .format does a bit of magic. If you for instance run the following code: 
`"{}".format("foo")` The result you get is "foo".

In this specific case, you seem to already be formatting something, without it actually changing something (I doubt you intended to request the same URL a bunch of times. If you did, the format isn't required in the first place).

Other than that; I can't reproduce the issue. I get a response 200 when trying this.

Comment: I'm actually trying to loop pages from page 1 to 262.

Comment: In that case you should use: "http://pann.nate.com/search/talk? searchType=A&q=%EB%AF%B8%EC%84%B8%EB%A8%BC%EC%A7%80&page={page}".format(page=i)

Answer (score 0):

You need the `http://` protocol indicator at the start of your url.

Answer (score 0):

> url = "http://pann.nate.com/search/talk? 
>          searchType=A&q=%EB%AF%B8%EC%84%B8%EB%A8%BC%EC%A7%80&page=1".format(i)

Try:

```
url = "http://pann.nate.com/search/talk? 
   searchType=A&q=%EB%AF%B8%EC%84%B8%EB%A8%BC%EC%A7%80&page={}".format(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this problem. I just had to designate the exact part of html that has #contentArea. I fixed my code as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


for i in range(1, 262) :
    url = "http://pann.nate.com/search/talk? 
q=%EB%AF%B8%EC%84%B8%EB%A8%BC%EC%A7%80&page={}".format(i)
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    list = soup.find_all("ul", {"class":"s_list"})

for i in range(1, len(list)) :
    a_list = list[i].select("dt")

for i in range(1, len(a_list)) :
    mylist = a_list[i].select("a")   

ln = []
for i in range(1, len(mylist)) :
    link = mylist[i].get('href')
    if len(link) > 2 and "javascript" not in link:
        ln.append(link)    

for i in range(1, len(ln)) :
    my_response = requests.get(ln[i]) 
    mysoup = BeautifulSoup(my_response.content, "html.parser")

filename = "natepan_dust.csv"
f = open(filename, "w", encoding='UTF-8')

headers = "title, time, content/n"

f.write("headers")

for i in range(1, len(mysoup)) :
    a_title = mysoup.select("h4")
    title = a_title[0].text

    a_time = mysoup.findAll("span", {"class":"date"})
    time = a_time[0].text

    content = mysoup.select_one("#contentArea").text

    print("title: " + title)
    print("time: " + time)
    print("content: " + content)

    f.write(title.replace(","," ") + "," + time + "," + 
content.replace(","," ") + "\n")

f.close()
```

However! I got another problem. I can't loop through pages from 1 to 262.
The CSV file I got at the end only contains the data from the last page.
What have I done wrong??